# How to manually acknowledge RabbitMQ messages in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-amqp

For stream-based services, I want the message to remain in the queue when the underlying service invoked within a `@StreamListener` fails. To that end, my understanding is that the only way to do this is to configure `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel_name.consumer.acknowledge-mode=MANUAL`.

After making this configuration change, I tried adding `@Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,@Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag` as method arguments to my existing `@StreamListener` implementation as documened at https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-ack. With this code in place, I encountered the following exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:941)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:851)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:771)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:198)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:752)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1224)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1470)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'amqp_channel' for method parameter type [interface com.rabbitmq.client.Channel]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:100)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:103)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112)
```

I then found the following: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_usage_examples, which shows an example of how to perform acknowledgement of messages using Kafka, but I am currently using the RabbitMQ binding. We plan on eventually moving to Kafka, but for now, how do I configure and code a solution to do manual message acknowledgement for successfully processed messages and manual message rejection, thus leaving the message on the queue, when exceptions are encountered. I am currently on Spring Cloud `Edgware.RELEASE` and Spring Cloud Stream `Ditmars.RELEASE`.

**UPDATE**

Now I have the following configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        do-something-async-reply:
          group: xyz-service-do-something-async-reply
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          do-something-async-reply:
            consumer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              dlqDeadLetterExchange:
              dlqTtl: 10000
              requeueRejected: true
```

And I'm receiving the following error at service startup:

```
2018-01-12 14:46:34.346 ERROR [xyz-service,,,] 2488 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'do-something-async-reply.xyz-service-do-something-async-reply' in vhost '/': received the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

What configuration is wrong/am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property name is incorrect; you are missing `.rabbit`. It's

> spring.cloud.stream.**rabbit**.bindings.`<channel>`.consumer.acknowledge-mode=MANUAL

since this is a rabbit-specific property - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties).

**EDIT**

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So481977082Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So481977082Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void in(String in, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(in);
        Thread.sleep(60_000);
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
        System.out.println("Ackd");
    }

}
```

Bear in mind that the need for MANUAL acks is often a smell; it's generally better to let the container handle the acks; see `requeueRejected` at the same doco link. Unconditionally requeueing can cause an infinite loop.

**EDIT2**

Works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So48197708Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48197708Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> {
            output.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(@Header(name = "x-death", required = false) List<?> death) {
        System.out.println(death);
        throw new RuntimeException("x");
    }

}
```

with

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: foo
          content-type: application/json
          destination: foo
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
        output:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: foo
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              dlqDeadLetterExchange:
              dlqTtl: 10000
```

Result:

```
null
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: x
...
[{reason=expired, count=1, exchange=DLX, routing-keys=[foo.foo], time=Fri Jan 12 17:20:28 EST 2018, queue=foo.foo.dlq}, 
    {reason=rejected, count=1, exchange=foo, time=Fri Jan 12 17:20:18 EST 2018, routing-keys=[foo], queue=foo.foo}]
...

...
[{reason=expired, count=3, exchange=DLX, routing-keys=[foo.foo], time=Fri Jan 12 17:20:28 EST 2018, queue=foo.foo.dlq}, 
    {reason=rejected, count=3, exchange=foo, routing-keys=[foo], time=Fri Jan 12 17:20:18 EST 2018, queue=foo.foo}]
```

Comment: Gary, with requeueRejected set to true, will the message automatically get requeued when an exception is thrown from the `@StreamListener`? Is that all that needs to be done?

Comment: OK, I found some information about this at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_with_the_rabbitmq_binder. When the documentation states "Set the dlqDeadLetterExchange to the default exchange," what is the value for the default exchange?

Comment: Any exception except an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` will cause the message to be requeued, as long as retry is disabled. If retry is enabled, the binder will throw that exception when retries are exhausted. There is also `republishToDlq` where the binder will publish the failure, including headers containing information about the failure. The default exchange is an empty string. All queues are bound to that exchange with their queue name as the routing key.

Comment: OK, I believe I have my configuration correctly defined according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_with_the_rabbitmq_binder, but I'm receiving an error documented in the UPDATE to my original post. I've tried making some changes/additions, but I can't seem to figure out what I've specified incorrectly.

Comment: As it shows in [Putting it all together](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_putting_it_all_together) you just need to use a blank value for the `dlqDeadLetterExchange` not ''.

Comment: I removed the '' as reflected in the UPDATE, and I'm still getting the same error. I just added the `spring.cloud.stream.bindings...` configuration for reference purposes to my UPDATE as well. The error is stating that the problem is with the `group` channel (`xyz-service-do-something-async-reply`), which I want to send the message to. The configuration for that channel is in xyz-service.yml.

Comment: See my second edit for a working example. Since your queue exists already you have to delete it; you can't change arguments on an existing queue.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will take a look at it. There appears to be some sort of chicken/egg issue for me. After deleting the queue, the error no longer displays when starting the consumer service. However, when I start the producer service, that same error is displayed. The same queue name is referenced in the producer as follows: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.do-something-async-reply.producer.required-groups: xyz-service-do-something-async-reply`. What's interesting is on the consumer side I was seeing `received the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr' but current is none` and now the opposite.

Comment: Now I'm seeing on the producer side `received none but current is the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr'`.

Comment: Gary, I just figured out that I need the following configurations on the producer side: `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.do-something-async-reply.producer.auto-bind-dql:true`, `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.do-something-async-reply.producer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange:`, and `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.do-something-async-reply.producer.dlq.ttl: 10000`. No errors on either the consumer or producer side now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, if you have `required-groups` on the producer side (which forces consumer queue declaration), the queue binding configuration must match the consumer's configuration. It's generally best to decouple the consumer from the producer but `required-groups` is necessary if you might deploy a new producer before a new consumer.